# jquery UI sortable: how to leave the original visible until the drop?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

In the standard behavior demonstrated at http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/ when you drag an item in the list a placeholder element is displayed where the item would be dropped.

However, the original location of the item to be dropped is not indicated.

I would like to leave the original location visible until the drop, so that the visual feedback is analogous to the way the original is left in place for the "semi-transparent clone" option depicted at http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#visual-feedback

Is there any way I can do this with sortable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So one approach that seems to work (thought it's definitely a hack) is to pass the option

`start: function (e, ui) { ui.item.show();}`

which unhides the automatically hidden original (`ui.item`).

And, more generally, one can use the `start` function to modify the item.

Comment: But it desappear on drop

Comment: Nice. I also ended up adding a class on start and removing it on stop. I then set the opacity of the css class. I found this helped illustrate which one was the original item.

Answer (score 0):

The option `helper: 'clone'` will leave your original item in place, while creating a new DOM element that is actually dragged around by the mouse. (Additionally, you use the option `opacity: 0.7` to create the "semi-transparent" effect on the helper.)

I'm not sure if you'll need this, but if using a clone doesn't remove the item automatically from the list, you can then use the `remove` event to delete the item that was dragged out from the DOM entirely.

Comment: So, that's what I *thought* should happen with 'clone' -- but when I set helper: 'clone' the original still dissappears.

So perhaps I should ask: what could I be missing?

Comment: Looking at this more carefully, with 'clone' the item still appears in the DOM.  But it's not displayed.  

I modified the example that comes with the jquery-ui package to use the `helper: 'clone'` option, you can see it here:
http://brahn.sqprod.com/jq/sortable-example.html

Comment: And, in fact (thanks to Firebug) it's now clear that (again, even with the `clone` option) the original is hidden via setting the style to `display: none`

Comment: @brahn link dead :  brahn.sqprod.com/jq/sortable-example.html
jsfidler is the best to show exemple ...